# allocating memory sequencially in C

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I wanted to test `malloc()` to see if allocating to the same adress twice adds up to the memory, or just replaces it: `int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)); ptr = malloc(2*sizeof(int));`
 Will this memory be 3 ints large or just 2 ? 

When I test how many ints can fit in, I get about 200, after which I get errors during runtime. 
Can someone please explain the randomness of memory allocation ?

Comment: "allocating to the same address twice"??, i didn't get you.

Comment: You store a address in `ptr` The size of allocated memory is _not_ enforced! You can write integers till your system/program crashes.

Comment: You are not "allocating to the same address twice" and in fact that's not possible. You are allocating two objects and leaking one of them. Perhaps you have not yet discovered realloc.

Comment: @David Heffernan: He could allocate in place to verify his "same address twice" theory.

Comment: @CodeClown Please do elaborate on what "allocate in place" means.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Just put both test cases in two functions and use `alloca()` or `malloca()` for memory allocation. If the functions are called in a row, the allocation is on the same address,

Comment: @CodeClown The question concerns heap allocation. Your comments are off-topic.

Comment: What kind of errros are you seeing? Without seeing more code we won't be able to help with the errors.

Comment: `malloc` then `free` then `malloc` pretty much allocates to the same adress

Comment: @David Heffernen: Your initial comment suggested allocating at the same address is not possible. The OP is just asking about "allocating memory". I just want to add to it.

Comment: @CodeClown Do you think the asker is really ready for `alloca`? Anyway, I've said enough here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`malloc()` always allocates a new block of memory, of the size you request, assuming that memory is available. It returns a pointer to the first byte of the memory it allocated so that you can use it. When you do your second `malloc()` call, it overwrites the pointer to the memory you allocated in the first, so you can't access it anymore - but it's still there and it's still allocated to you. This is usually called a memory leak, because your process has grabbed memory and then not given it back despite no longer using it.

So after your second call, you've allocated enough memory to store three integers, in two separate blocks, the first of which can no longer be accessed because you don't have a pointer to it anymore.

There is no randomness in memory allocation.

I'm not sure why you're getting runtime errors when you get to 200 ints, unless your process has very constrained memory availability. It'd help to know what the errors you're getting actually are.

Comment: Through randomness, I was refering to the fact that i can fit in 200 ints in a supposed 4 byte memory block. I coined that it's actually a program crash, confused it with another error.

Comment: @kundrata If I understand correctly, writing `200` `int`s to a pointer that only had 4 bytes allocated to it is undefined behavior and will likely cause a crash if you keep writing.

Comment: Ah that explains a lot. You didn't explain in the question that you were then trying to write past the allocated range. That is indeed 'undefined behaviour' and a crash is the usual result, but not always, hence the randomness. You can usually stray a bit because you're still inside your own memory (but this may cause problems with other code of course), but once you go outside your process's memory the OS will object loudly.

Answer (score 1):

> Will this memory be 3 ints large or just 2 ?

`ptr` will point to memory for two `int`s when you reassign to `ptr` the previous memory location is now lost and that memory is leaked.

Comment: Good mentioning the leak.

Answer (score 0):

malloc simply return void pointer to the allocated memory.`2*sizeof(int)` will allocate 2*sizeof(int) `bytes` means memory for two integers.
Initially you gave memory for one integer only then again on same pointer you assigned memory for two integer.So finally it will point for two integer size space.